# How do I download last working project from TFS server and replace my local, which does not work?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

Apparently I have some problems with my local work-space and I not able to deploy anything to **TFS** server successfully.

Is it possible to download last working solution and replace my local?
If so, how?

Thank you for you help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source control explorer, right click on the folder you want to replace, navigate to "Advanced", and choose "Get Specific Version".

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you use TFVC and not git...)
yes, of course, you can. do you know the type of your workspace (local\server)?

in any way you can get specific version from the context menu, then choose the latest version: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0wDf.png)
if you want, you can delete ALL local content before, make to select the checkboxes to overwirte the local and ignore the disk

If your workspace is large, you can use scorch command instead:
tf vc scorch
this command checks the disk with the server and removes untracked files